# Add style to an element with Javascript

Tags: jquery, css, slidedown

I've added a simple jquery slideDown function to a client's website but they want to add some style via javascript so that for anyone with JS disabled they still see the content.

```
<script>
    $(".click").click(function () {
        $(".morecontent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

.morecontent is currently set to display:none via the stylesheet, so basically I want to include this style in the script as oppose to the stylesheet

Comment: You are contradicting yourself: "add some style via javascript" and "for anyone with JS disabled" don't got together.  If they have JS disabled, none of your script will run at all.

Comment: well if a browser has js disabled then you whont be able to add the style to show the content with js ( becouse js is disabled isn't it ?)

Comment: what actually is your problem?

Comment: @AleksG You don't understand the question. I will offer a simplified view: `No JS = display:inline`. When JS is enabled: `set display:none, then show the element using slideToggle`. Read the bottom of my answer for a more clear description.

Comment: Sorry, I've not had my morning coffee yet.

Basically for users with JS disabled the .morecontent div would be visible from the start (ie; no need to click anything to show it).

For users with JS enabled, it would be hidden to begin with, and on clicking the .click element it would slide down.

Thanks for all your help guys, it works like a charm now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the CSS using jQuery, use:

```
$(".morecontent").css("display", "none");
```

The `display:none` property can also be set by using `.hide()`. **Note: You should call this code when the document is ready**, ie, the element is already defined. To achieve this, use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".morecontent").hide();
})
```

When JavaScript is disabled, the elements will be visible (because the `display:none` at the stylesheet has been removed). When JavaScript is enabled, the script will hide the `.morecontent`, so that it can be slided in.

Comment: have you read the question ? if js is disabled then you're solution whont work would it ?

Comment: @PoelincaDorin Do you understand the question? I have explained the behavior at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This worked a treat. Sorry for my poor descriptive skills this morning (No morning coffee)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `display:none` in the style sheet and hide the elements with the class morecontent using jQuery when the page loads:

```
<script>
    $(".morecontent").hide();
    $(".click").click(function () {
        $(".morecontent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

This might cause a flicker as elements are hidden when the page is loaded. You can get around this by hiding the entire page `$('body').hide();` at the top of the page and showing it again at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('.morecontent').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(".morecontent").css ( {display: "none" } );
    $(".click").click(function () {
        $(".morecontent").slideToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```